# Is there a security benefit to only putting PHP code in '*.php' files?

Tags: php, html

I believe that this topic is very important to discuss a little bit since it is making some confusion for me. I want to know if I use php code in html page, is that the same level of security as when I use php code in php page? how about the opposite way? I tested a php code to whether I can see it or not on localhost and web server and it turned out that nether show the php code. Does that mean both page format are the same?? so why do we have to have different types if that's true then?

are there a substantial or essential meaning or benefits of having php over html as some article suggest? for me, I see both do the same job.

I want to hear your opinions if you don't mind.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing inherently secure or insecure about a filename extension; in fact, [you can configure your webserver to treat any file as a PHP script.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/mod/core.html#sethandler)

Comment: Thanks @Phoenix. I'm speechless. The link you provided teaches a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write PHP, you're essentially writing a program that outputs HTML.  PHP runs server-side.  The browser has no knowledge that the HTML page was created in PHP.

As far as "page format", you are simply referring to the file name extension, `.php` or `.html`.  These are meaningless to the browser.  The browser only cares about `Content-Type` which is a header sent outside of the page itself.

The file name extension is mainly useful for telling your web server what to do with the file.  When it sees `.php`, it passes the page contents off to PHP to process.  PHP then passes the output back to the server, and the server sends it to the browser.

Comment: well said @Brad. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between then two. However you should always try to keep php and html separate as far as possible to making maintenance easier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62617/whats-the-best-way-to-separate-php-code-and-html is worth a read

Comment: Thanks @Iamplightdev. That was a great comment, and the link,too.

Answer (score 2):

When you put code in a `.html` file, it's possible that your server doesn't parse it as PHP.

Code between `<? ... ?>` are generally not visible in browsers, so you should be careful.

Comment: nice comment @Rob. all appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can not believe you are asserting that `HTML` and `PHP` are the same. `HTML` is the markup. Alone it is only a markup for *static* web pages, `.html` files. `PHP` is a language that helps you create *dynamic* web pages together with a web server (e.g. [Apache Web Server](http://httpd.apache.org/)).

The Web Server will be instructed to parse all PHP code `<?php [code] ?>` in all available PHP file extensions: `.php`, `.phtml`, `.php4`, `.php3`, `.php5`, `.phps`. That's why you can not see `PHP` code when it is already served to a web browser.

If your Web Server is correctly configured you should never be able to download a non-parsed `PHP` code. So there is not an intrinsic security risk there.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. well, I guess you it is expected from beginners to ask such a question, isn't it? you're comments are also great. Thanks